# Flutter : delay on loading images in PageView

Tags: flutter

I am using a `DecorationImage` inside `PageView`.

If I use 5 images or more, there is a slight delay in making the image appear. It shows the background color for a very brief moment when I swipe left, and then it is replaced by the next page with the correct background.

If I use 4 images or less, this issue does not appear.

Here's a working example of that issue:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
          checkerboardRasterCacheImages: true,
          title: 'Problem Images',
          home: ProblemWidget()),
    );
  }
}

class ProblemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ProblemWidget> createState() => _ProblemWidgetState();
}

class _ProblemWidgetState extends State<ProblemWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ImageProvider> images = [
      const AssetImage('assets/images/0.jpg'),
      const AssetImage('assets/images/1.jpg'),
      const AssetImage('assets/images/2.jpg'),
      const AssetImage('assets/images/3.jpg'),
      const AssetImage('assets/images/4.jpg'),
      const AssetImage('assets/images/5.jpg'),
      const AssetImage('assets/images/6.jpg'),
      const AssetImage('assets/images/7.jpg'),
    ];

    // images.removeRange(2, images.length); // uncommenting this image makes the problem disappear

    return PageView.builder(
      controller: PageController(
        viewportFraction: 0.9999, // HACK to ensure preload of next page
        initialPage: 0,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: images[index % images.length], fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is driving me crazy. Does anyone know what's going on there?

Comment: Try to set allowImplicitScrolling to true

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/preload_page_view this might help.